# React Apollo used to set a cookie with userID

Tags: node.js, cookies, redis, apollo-server, express-session

What I would like to do is:

1. create login mutation and return using it user id and username
2. add a cookie to a browser (chrome) with user id to check if user is logged in or not

Login mutation works if I do not assign userId to session, works means it returns requested data.
However when I add below line of code to add userId to session, it creates a cookie but I can't fetch data (userId and userName):

```
req.session!.userId = user.id;
```

I receive information i can't fetch data, please check your connection.
I am not sure when I am making mistake, any help appreciated.

Below I provide my setup:

index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import microConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql';
import { HelloResolver } from "./resolvers/hello";
import { PostResolver } from "./resolvers/post";
import { UserResolver } from "./resolvers/user";
import session from 'express-session';
import IORedis from "ioredis";
import { MyContext } from "./types";
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from "apollo-server-core";

const main = async () => {
    //console.log("dirname: ", __dirname);

    // connect db
    const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);
    // run migrations
    await orm.getMigrator().up();

    const app = express();

    // importing connect redis causing issue with session object
    const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)
    //const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
    //const redisClient = redis.createClient();
    const redisClient: IORedis.Cluster = new IORedis.Cluster([])

// https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/issues/300
// installed ioredis
    app.use(
        session({
          name: "rjsession",
          store: new RedisStore({
               client: redisClient,
               disableTouch: true,
             }),
          cookie: {
                 maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10, // 10 years
                 httpOnly: true,
                 sameSite: 'lax',
                 //secure: __prod__, //cookie works only in https, on dev good to run off
                 secure: false,
             },
          saveUninitialized: false,
          secret: 'keyboard catadasdasdsdaasdadas',
          resave: false,
        })
      )

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await buildSchema( {
            resolvers: [HelloResolver, PostResolver, UserResolver],
            validate: false,
        }),
        context: ({ req, res }): MyContext => ({ em: orm.em, req, res }),
        // added plugin to force apollo server to use old graphql playground
        plugins: [
            ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground({
                // options

            })
        ],
    });
    
    await apolloServer.start();

    
    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ 
        app,
        cors: { credentials: true, origin: ["http://localhost:4000/"] },
     });
    
    

    app.listen(4000, () => {
        console.log("server started on localhost: 4000")
    })

    app.get('/', (_, res) => {
        res.send("hello");
        
    })
};

// catch error and print it
main().catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

login mutation definition:

```
    @Mutation(() => UserResponse)
    async login(
        @Arg('options') options: UsernamePasswordInput,
        @Ctx() { em, req }: MyContext
    ): Promise<UserResponse> {
        // check if user registered
        const user = await em.findOne(User, { username: options.username });

        // if user null return password
        if (!user) {    
            return {
                errors: [
                    {
                        field: "username",
                        message: "User does not exist.",
                    },
                ],
            };
        }
        // validate password against user input
        const valid = await argon2.verify(user.password, options.password);

        // return error if password failed validation
        if (!valid){
            return {
                errors: [
                    {
                        field: "password",
                        message: "password incorrect.",
                    },
                ],
            };
        }

        // asign user id in cookies

        req.session!.userId = user.id;
        console.log(req.session!.userId)

        //req.session!.userId = user.id;
        // if no errors return user
        return {
            user,
        };  
    }
```

types.ts file:

```
import { EntityManager, IDatabaseDriver, Connection } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { Response, Request} from 'express'
//import { Request } from 'express-serve-static-core'



export type MyContext = {
    em: EntityManager<any> & EntityManager<IDatabaseDriver<Connection>>
    //req: Request & {session: Express.Session} & { userId: number };
    //req: Request & {session: Session};
    req: Request; // & {session: Express.Session};
    res: Response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current code, you are using `req.session!.userId` only at one place, and you use you are getting error. That makes me think that you have an issue with redis.

When you login, your server is going to generate a session id which is stored on the Redis store. Since your redis is not running on your machine, you cannot store it so you are getting error.

Before you start your application, start the redis server first.